# Find an exact constant

Tags: real-analysis, functions, multivariable-calculus, inequality

Let $\nu\ge 1$ be a parameter.

For all $t>0,$ we consider
\begin{align}
A(t) & =\frac{1-\cos(t\sqrt{4\nu-1})}{4\nu-1}-(\cosh(t)-1) \\
g(t) & =\frac{\frac{\sin(t\sqrt{4\nu-1})}{\sqrt{4\nu-1}}+\sinh(t)}{A(t)} \
\end{align}

We have $$g(t)\le g(3\nu^{-\frac{1}{3}})$$ for all $t\le 3\nu^{-\frac{1}{3}}$

I want to determine a constant $c<-1$ such that $$g(3\nu^{-\frac{1}{3}})\le c$$

Please help me to do so.

Thanks.

Comment: For which $\nu$ is this supposed to hold?

Comment: this supposed to hold for $\nu\ge1$

Comment: So, why don't you write this? This is not obvious at all.

Comment: sorry i will edit that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like $g(3\nu^{-1/3})$ is a decreasing function of $\nu$ for $\nu > 1$.  Thus you should be able to take the value at $\nu = 1$:

$$ c = \frac{-\sqrt{3} \sin(3\sqrt{3})-3\sinh(3)}{\cos(3\sqrt{3})+3\cosh(3)-4} $$

which is approximately $-1.069454721$.

Comment: how do you proved that $g(3\nu^{-1/3})$ is a is a decreasing function of $\nu$? i tried to do that but i didn't manage, can you please help me to prove that ? thanks in advance

Comment: I didn't prove it (that's why I wrote "It looks to me like ...").  It is true asymptotically as $\nu \to \infty$, and it is true numerically for $\nu$ in some interval.  In principle it should be possible to turn that into a proof, but the details may be tedious.

Comment: can us show that there exist a constant $c>0$ which dosn't depend on $\nu$  such that $$ln(1-\frac{2}{g(t)+1})\ge c$$ for all $t\le 3\nu^{\frac{-1}{3}}$? thanks